# Netbeans 8.1 Gnome 3 GTK+ UI Font and tabs height

Tags: java, netbeans, tabs, gtk

I just installed NetBeans 8.1 at Ubuntu 16.04 running GNOME 3 desktop. I would like to keep using the GTK+ Look & Feel of the IDE if possible but the font on the UI especially in the tab is way too small and overlapping.

[image]

I tried adding `--fontsize 15` into the argument at `/etc/netbeans.conf` file but no help.

What can I do to fix this? I don't seems to have this problem on NetBeans 8.0.2 previously.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to resolved it by changing the font face and font size of GNOME using the Tweak Tool >  Font

Comment: I am using Debian Gnome-shell. By default it used Cantarell Bold/Regular fonts. Changing them into Sans Bold/Regular fixed it for me. Perhaps the font is missing something that JRE cannot use.

Comment: Changing settings by single entry is not the best idea, you will have to tweak it. Check my answer of using different netbeans theme.

Answer (score 6):

For me it worked running netbeans with "Metal Look and Feel"
 (http://wiki.netbeans.org/NBLookAndFeels)

```
./netbeans --laf Metal
```

Running GTK 3.22 on Fedora 25.

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same problem and filed a bug in the NetBeans bug database.
There is a work around, though: You can use a different look and feel. If you choose metal or Nimbus instead of the system look and feel (gtk3), there is no problem.
The Darcula theme is especially noteworthy, as it is really good looking, it is a dark theme, though. You can install it as a plugin from the NetBeans Plugin installer.

Answer (score 3):

For me the solution was to set the Look and Feel to `Metal` in `Tools > Options`.

See  [image: screebshot]

Answer (score 1):

Check which jre you use to run NetBeans. If it's openjdk, try installing oracle jdk. Or, even better, try openjdk with font fix: https://github.com/achaphiv/ppa-fonts/tree/master/openjdk-fontfix

It makes font rendering look almost native on swing apps. I believe IntelliJ now ships their own similarly patched JRE to work around font issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing  [Darcula LAF for Netbeans](https://github.com/bulenkov/Darcula) from plugins

[image: Darcula]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible for Nimbus. Add the following parameters to `netbeans.conf`

```
--laf Nimbus -J-Dswing.aatext=true -J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
```