# Strange fonts in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, fonts, gtk

I have Ubuntu: 16.04.4 LTS and NetBeans: 8.2 (Build 201609300101)
And, I have may be stupid question which I don't know where to start looking from.
I have kind of "miraged", "dualing", "reflecting" font in place of bold font in NetBeans menu... 
How can I get the normal font back?

[image: Strange font]

**UPD**: The problem just with GTK+ look and feel.

Comment: have you tried looiking in the look and feel settings?https://jaxenter.com/netbeans/the-complete-guide-to-tuning-the-appearance-of-netbeans may help you find the setting (don't have nb on my currently available  machine so i cannot check atm

Comment: OK, I changed Look and Feel to Metal instead of GTK+, it get rid of mirages, but is it possible to solve it for GTK+? (The link above don't provide the solution)

Comment: Does this SO post help?... [Netbeans 8.1 Gnome 3 GTK+ UI Font and tabs height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846159/netbeans-8-1-gnome-3-gtk-ui-font-and-tabs-height)

Comment: No, it will change fonts systemwide